# Turning on/off Phillips Android 7100 TV backlight/ambilight

Tags: android, television, android-tv, backlight

I've been trying to code a simple Android app that just `turns on and off the Phillips Android 7100 TV backligth/ambilight`.

To achieve this, I have considered the following possibilities:

- Use the Phillips SDK
- Use a generic native Android TV "framework" function

Both would be completely valid.

Sincerely, `I consider there is such a lack of documentation on this matter`.

---

Please share any related material that could be useful to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for [Philips Hue API](http://www.developers.meethue.com/).

Phillips Android 7100 TV has integrated Hue Lights.